# How to get/change Image Source name with code in Unity?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

we made a script and need to get the image name, we implement this task with a clumsy way below, but we still want to know whether there is a way to get the image name directly?

[image]

```
public class CubeManager
{
    static public Dictionary<CubeType, string> cubeTypeDict = new Dictionary<CubeType, string>();
    static private Dictionary<string, GameObject> cubeDict = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
    static CubeManager()
    {
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall01, "Wall01");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall02, "Wall02");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall03, "Wall03");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall04, "Wall04");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall05, "Wall05");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall06, "Wall06");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall07, "Wall07");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall08, "Wall08");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall09, "Wall09");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall10, "Wall10");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall11, "Wall11");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall12, "Wall12");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall13, "Wall13");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall14, "Wall14");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall15, "Wall15");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall16, "Wall16");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall17, "Wall17");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall18, "Wall18");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall19, "Wall19");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall20, "Wall20");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall21, "Wall21");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall22, "Wall22");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall23, "Wall23");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall24, "Wall24");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall25, "Wall25");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall26, "Wall26");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall27, "Wall27");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall28, "Wall28");
        cubeTypeDict.Add(CubeType.Wall29, "Wall29");
    }
```

Comment: have you tried Image.sprite.texture.ToString() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can by,

```
Image img;

Debug.Log("Image Name: " + img.sprite.name);
```

Additionally you can change sprite as well by giving `Texture2D`

```
img.sprite = Sprite.Create (spr.texture, img.sprite.rect, new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f));
```

Here `spr` is a Sprite, you can use `Texture2D` directly.

Comment: You again:) but this is gameobject name , not the source image name, right?

Comment: It is source image name :)

Comment: BTW, is there a way to change the image too? I mean the change is not only about the image name but also the image itself, e.g. from a image A to a image B.

Comment: Yea, my answer's second part doest that

Answer (score 1):

`this.transform.gameobject.GetComponent<Image> ().name;`

Comment: Please add explanation and more context to your answer.